# NullPointException in drag and drop of ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to move the image from one place to another.

Now the image is held by the `ImageView` and I am drawing the drag and drop with `OnDragListener` but it return the null point exception and the application got crash is there any other way to implement the drag and drop and any solution for this problem.

Here is my main activity code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ima = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_logo);

    ima.setTag(IMAGEVIEW_TAG);

    ima.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence)v.getTag());

            String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};
            ClipData dragData = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(),
                    mimeTypes, item);

            // Instantiates the drag shadow builder.
            View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new DragShadowBuilder(ima);

            // Starts the drag
            v.startDrag(dragData,  // the data to be dragged
                    myShadow,  // the drag shadow builder
                    null,      // no need to use local data
                    0          // flags (not currently used, set to 0)
            );
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

This is my Drag and drop code:

```
ima.setOnDragListener( new OnDragListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v,  DragEvent event){
        switch(event.getAction())
        {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                        v.getLayoutParams();
                Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
                int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                int y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :
                Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
                x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
                layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord;
                v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION  :
                Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION");
                x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED   :

                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                break;

            default: break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Please post your `logcat`

Answer (score 2):

I forget this in my activity:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```